# SQL Server Computed Column: how to set it to NOT NULL, without persistence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, calculated-columns

**I am adding a computed column, which should be `NOT NULL` on an existing table.**
Both my source column for the computed value are `NOT NULL` of course. I would like to make the computed column not persistent, to save space, but I fail to do so:

```
ALTER TABLE UnitHistory
ADD 
    [PrefixedUnitId] AS ((UnitHistory.UnitIdPrefix + cast(UnitHistory.UnitId     
    AS nvarchar(8)))) NOT NULL
GO
```

gives

> Only UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraints can be created on computed
>   columns, while CHECK, FOREIGN KEY, and NOT NULL constraints require
>   that computed columns be persisted. Msg 15135, Level 16, State 15,
>   Procedure sp_addextendedproperty, Line 72 Object is invalid. Extended
>   properties are not permitted on 'dbo.UnitHistory.PrefixedUnitId', or
>   the object does not exist.

Now, I understand what the message says, and sure enough, using `PERSISTED NOT NULL` does produce the column.

**To save space however, I would like to have the column not be persisted.**

**Is there a way to have a computed column NOT NULL, but not persistent, when the underlying columns are NOT NULL?**

Note: It should work on a SQL Server 2012 SP2

Comment: It's not immediately clear why you need this constraint. The only way this column could be NULL is if either of the source columns (`UnitIdPrefix` and `UnitId`) is NULL. You can check for this by setting NOT NULL on the source columns (if they aren't already).

Comment: @EdHarper *"Both my source column for the computed value are NOT NULL of course"*.

Comment: @Marcel Wrap the column expression in an `isnull(..., N'')`.

Comment: `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` are the only expressions that will set the "not nullable" flag for metadata discovery purposes. All other expressions, even the most trivial ones, will mark the computed column as nullable (save for a direct alias of a non-nullable column, e.g. `ComputedColumn AS NonNullableColumn`), regardless of whether the expression can ever actually yield `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

This seems totally redundant, but you can repeat the condition in a `check` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE UnitHistory
    ADD PrefixedUnitId AS ( UnitHistory.UnitIdPrefix + cast(UnitHistory.UnitId AS nvarchar(8)) );

ALTER TABLE UnitHistory
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK ( UnitHistory.UnitIdPrefix + cast(UnitHistory.UnitId AS nvarchar(8)) IS NOT NULL );
```

However, because the source columns are `NOT NULL`, the result can never be `NULL`.

The notion of non-persisted computed columns is that they are calculated on *output* not *input*. I think this explains why `check` constraints are not appropriate.

For instance, you can have a table that has a computed column that generates an error and still fully use the table:

```
create table t (
    id int identity primary key,
    x int,
    computed as (1 / 0)
);

-- works
insert into t (x) values (1);

-- works
select x
from t;

-- fails
select *
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dc9454726ca1ad254535b487b01c3623) is a db<>fiddle.

Incidentally, a computed column that always generates an error has a nice side effect -- it prevents users from using `select *` if that is something you want to do.

Comment: I find using a constraint rather odd. Would an ORM like Entity Framework or a Browser like MSSQL Studio handle that as intended (processing the column as NOT NULL)?

Comment: @Marcel . . . No.  `NOT NULL` is a special type of constraint that is stored in the data pages using a `NULL` bit in SQL Server.  In other words, if you want something to be fully understood as `NOT NULL` you *have to persist it*.

Comment: God himself answered this question! Amem! @GordonLinoff, I'm a big fan!